# Correct logical equivalent of "Every real number except zero has multiplicative inverse."

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

1. My Discrete Mathematics textbook translates the statement "Every real number except zero has multiplicative inverse" to $$\forall{x}{({(x\neq0)} \rightarrow{\exists{y}{(xy=1)}})}.\tag1$$ I noticed that the above translation is correct if and only if you interpret the original English statement as not specifying whether zero has multiplicative inverse. That is, all numbers have inverses except zero for which zero may or may not have an inverse. (This is evident from the truth table in which if $x$ was equal to zero then whether $x$ has an inverse or not the statement evaluates to true in both cases.) In the same vein, I can say that "Every real number greater than 7 has a multiplicative inverse" translates to $$\forall{x}{({(x>7)} \rightarrow{\exists{y}{(xy=1)}})};$$ this statement doesn't mean that only real numbers greater than $7$ have a multiplicative inverse.
2. However, if you interpret the original English statement as "Every real number except zero has multiplicative inverse while zero does not have a multiplicative inverse", then this translates to $$\forall{x}{({(x\neq0)} \leftrightarrow{\exists{y}{(xy=1)}})}.\tag2$$

My professor translated the original sentence the same way the book did. So, I asked whether he assumed that zero has multiplicative inverse, and he answered with a yes because we know that zero does not have a multiplicative inverse. I then explained what I wrote above, but I couldn't get my point across, and he insisted that his translation was correct.

Is what I wrote above correct, or is the first translation indeed the only correct one? Is "Every real number except zero has multiplicative inverse" ambiguous or is $(1)$ or $(2)$ its correct logical equivalent?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: It is possible to say, that you both are right, because both sentences are correct. If we know, that equivalence is correct, then implication is correct also. Your one implies other, of course.

Comment: Usually when you publish a theorem like $X \implies Y$, you want the weakest $X$ and the strongest $Y$ you can.  Because $A \implies B$ is weaker than $A \iff B$, it is preferred as an assumption, as long as it actually works.

Comment: @DanielV Could you please expand on that a little or point me in the right direction to read more on the subject. Thank you.

Comment: @PsychicLegend What I wrote is so mundane that I doubt anyone has written much on it.  It is the basis of Hoare logic but that is way beyond the scope of your question.  Is there some aspect of what I said that wasn't clear to you?  Like is the concept of strong/weak propositions clear?

Comment: @DanielV Yes. I know that implies is weaker than iff but I didn't completely understand what you meant by the weakest $X$ and the strongest $Y$. Now i know (correct if I'm wrong here) that for example p="I am student" is weaker than q="I am a student and I love basketball". If we took these two examples and applied what you said on them then we get $p\rightarrow q$ which, the way I see it, is wrong and it must be $q\rightarrow p$ since if I was in a more specific case (stronger proposition) then I am for sure in the more general one (weaker proposition) but not vice versa.

Comment: @DanielV So, my questions are:
1. Is my understanding of strong and weak proposition correct
2. and if so, wouldn't we want strong implies weak instead of the opposite
Thank you for being patient and sorry if I'm asking a lot of questions but I always like to understand the topic at hand the best I could.

Comment: @DanielV Just one more question. I get that one must use the weaker form a compound proposition if he's not sure of the correctness of the stronger one, but why would we want to use the weaker form of a compound proposition if we know for a fact that the stronger form is more correct and more true to real life.

Comment: @zkutch Hmm, the OP's title does particularly specify 'logical equivalence', which is what it means anyway to translate between natural and formal language. Otherwise, one might argue that `∃x∈N x>0` is a "correct" translation of 'every natural number is positive', since, after all, both statements are true and thus mathematically equivalent to each other.

Answer (score 2):

If you can establish that $\forall x . x \cdot 0 = 0$, then that already implies $\forall x \bigg( x \ne 0 \leftarrow \bigg(\exists y. xy=1\bigg) \bigg) $ .  So the $\leftarrow$ direction of the $\iff$ is usually already redundant.  But it isn't wrong, so all that is left is style.

And as a general point of style and usefulness, search for assumptions that are as weak as possible but still strong enough to be sufficient.  Aim for conclusions that are as strong as possible, but weak enough to still be correct.

The set of natural numbers that is divisible by 6 is a strict subset of those that are divisible by 2.  So $6|x$ is a strictly stronger claim than $2|x$.  If I tell you $6|x$ then I have told you "more information" than if I have only told you $2|x$.  On the other hand, if I say "I will let you out of jail if you find me an $x$ divisible by 6", then I am asking more of you than the other jailer who would release you for only finding and even $x$.

Strong/weak is a strictly partial order.  For the two statements $x > 1000$ as well as $x \text{ is even}$, neither is stronger or weaker than the other.  The set of numbers satisfying the first is neither a superset nor a subset of the second.

If you are offering the theorem $X \to Y$ to the world:  If $X$ is too strong, no one can ever use it.  If $Y$ is too weak, there is no reason to use it.  An example of a very useless theorem would be $z = 178462827 \implies z = z$.  Who cares about $178462827$? That is too strong of a requirement.  And $z=z$ is such a weak claim that is always true.  Not helpful.

Implications $X \to Y$ are 3 parts:  the assumption $X$, the conclusion $Y$, and the implication $X \to Y$.  When you offer a theorem, you want to offer the strongest not-wrong version of the theorem.  An implication is strengthened by weakening the conclusion.  An implication is strengthened by strengthening the conclusion.

The weakest possible implication is $\text{false implies true}$.  It is so weak that it manifests both meanings of "vacuously true".

Now as a disclaimer, there is some cheating going on here, because every mathematical theorem when written out with *all* of the assumptions that goes into it is a tautology, so in that context every mathematical theorem is technically equally strong.  So if you wanted to get into formal logic, all this only applies to domain specific way theorems are presented, not to the entire tautological version of theorems.

> Now i know (correct if I'm wrong here) that for example p="I am student" is weaker than q="I am a student and I love basketball".

Correct.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for taking the time to clarify that up.

Answer (score 0):

- The word 'except' or 'exception' almost certainly indicates an exclusion from a category/rule/pattern, rather than that the referent is being excluded merely from description/characterisation. So, I think that
  $$\forall{x}{({(x\neq0)} \leftrightarrow{\exists{y}{(xy=1)}})}.\tag2$$ is indeed the the correct formalisation of (i.e., logically equivalent to)

  - Every number **except zero** has multiplicative inverse.
- On the other hand,  $$\forall{x}{({(x\neq0)} \rightarrow{\exists{y}{(xy=1)}})}.\tag1$$ is logically equivalent to

  - Every **non-zero** number has a multiplicative inverse.